# Phonegap 3.0.0 not working with iPhone 5 and having problems with iOS 7.0.1

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I tried this article, but it was no help: I could not even get to the splash screen for this article to be relevant.  http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/_phonegap_build_iphone_5_support_armv6_update

The phonegap app was working and being tested on the iPhone 4 which had an older version - not sure which version because I did not check, but definitely older than 7.0.0.

All of a sudden, I plug in an iPhone 5, with version 7.0.1 on it, and iTunes asks me to update to 11.1.1 to make the phone compatible - no problem I do it.

However, the app does not work on the iPhone 5 - by not work I mean that it appears to load, but the icon is 95% blackened (I can see the icon faintly, but its mostly dark/black), and when I press it, it is as if I am pressing the background of the page - nothing happens.

Using the exact same computer/iTunes, I test the same iPhone 4 again - this time it had been upgraded to version 7.0.2 (to see if it was a version compatibility thing), and it did, in fact load to the phone, and was good to test.  The app DID regress a bit and lose some features and need some fixing with the new version (one being the cosmetic overlay that the new version adds to the top of the screen - that 20-px transparent overlay that covers my buttons, but that can be moved down with version detection I assume).

The app works and can be tested on the iPhone 4, but not on the iPhone 5 - similar versions (7.0.2 vs 7.0.1) and same iTunes (11.1.1).

Please help! :-)